# Are there any standard algorithms or techniques to create Thinkmap/Constellation-style software

Tags: user-interface, animation

I'm not talking about utilising them to browse my own data set.  I'm talking about actually writing one.  Are there algorithms for where the circles move and how they move around slickly and in such a liquid way.  If anyone could even point me towards a book or a general area that would be great because I don't know where to start!

You can find examples of each at:

http://asterisq.com/products/constellation/framework/implementations

and

http://www.visualthesaurus.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at is called a force-directed graph. Google for that and you should find some helpful documentation. The math is surprisingly straightforward.

(By **munificent** on Games Development Stack Exchange)